# Left half-rounded border

Tags: css, border, rounded-corners

I'm wondering how to achieve this kind of css active style link shape I designed, should i create a specific shape for the left rounded part or should I just use border-left and try to tweak it ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `::after` css pseudo element for this. Here is example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezqbxp0w/). Hope this helps you.

```css
.link {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background: red;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .link::after{
        content: "";
        height: 80%;
        background: #fff;
        width: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10%;
        left: -10px;
        border-radius: 20px;
            transition: all .35s;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .link:hover::after{opacity:1}
```

```html
  <div class="link"></div>
```

Check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp). You can lean more about CSS Pseudo-elements from there.

Comment: Oh it's perfect, i need to learn how to use after/before element, so that i don't need to add an element on my whole list. Perfect.

Comment: Happy to help you.

Answer (score 4):

try using border radius like this

```css
div {
  width: 10px;
  height:40px;
  background-color: black;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Do you think it's possible to have the cutted part on the left ? Maybe playing on the position ?

Comment: just replace `border-top-right-radius` to `border-top-left-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius` to `border-bottom-left-radius`